# No route found for "GET https://localhost/register"

Tags: php, symfony, php-8, symfony6

I've been following a guide on the official Symfony site, for setting up users via the bundle symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle, and the make:user and make:registration_form commands.

Everything is fine, the Symfony default page is displayed, but in the guide it says "go to /register" in the browser, and when I do so, I get

> No route found for "GET https://localhost/register"

After clearing the cache and checking the routes, I do see the route as available, and when I issue a route match command with "php bin/console router:match /register" I get this output:

```
 [OK] Route "app_register" matches                                                                                                                                                                                                           

+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                          |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | app_register                                                   |
| Path         | /register                                                      |
| Path Regex   | {^/register$}sDu                                               |
| Host         | ANY                                                            |
| Host Regex   |                                                                |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                            |
| Method       | GET|HEAD                                                       |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                      |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::register() |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler        |
|              | utf8: true                                                     |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, everything looks fine.
Additional notes...I'm using Symfony 6.0, and PHP8 with attributes, so my route function has this header:

```
#[Route(path: '/register', name: 'app_register', methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'])]
```

...but as I wasn't getting anywhere, I also added this in my routes.yaml file

```
app_register:
    path: /register
    controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::register
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD']
```

But still, I get the exception when trying to navigate to that page. I've tried switching to an annotation header in the code, but still the same issue.

Before I start debugging the issue in depth I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue or knows the reason.

Thank you SO much for any help!

Comment: So what happened when you used make:controller to add a new route?  And have you accepted the fact that in Symfony it is quite common to use GET and POST on the same route with a single action method?  Just curious.

Comment: I didn’t, I used make:registration-form which created the RegistrationController, User entity, and template. It added the routing as attributes in the controller methods (as it’s PHP 8). At that point, going to /register should resolve to the controller method, but it doesn’t.

Comment: As for the GET and POST using the same URL action, that’s not a “Symfony thing”, that’s an architectural thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are used a virtual server like Laragon. Are you set .htaccess to omit index.php folder? do this test and try with http://localhost/index.php/register

Or you can exec with symfony cli

```
symfony serve
```

and then use the default port 8000
http://localhost:8000/register

For the route you are not need to set route.yaml file, the framework read your controller and set this route automatically

Comment: I use containers for all my work/research. I'm sure it was just something in my setup, but I wasn't making progress on the problem fast enough, so I just built the application without a framework.

Comment: Ok. I prefer use always a framework for all my applications or simple website because with a framework you have some consolidate security logical and them best practices that sometimes we forget 